# Determine constants and probability with density function

Tags: probability, statistics

Do not have answers to this problem

Please let me know if there is mistake or assistance in complete

Remi works at a large data center, and manages the hard drives for the servers. Hard drives often fail, and need to be replaced.

Assume that the probability density for a single hard drive failing after t days of use follows an exponential distribution:

$p(t) = Ce^{-λt}$ for $t ≥ 0$ where C and λ are constants.

a) Find C, in terms of λ.

b) Remi observes that the average failure time for the hard drives is 700 days. Use this to determine λ.

c) What is the probability that a single hard drive will last more that 2000 days?

Trial:

a)

\begin{align}
C\int_0^{∞} e^{-tλ}dt &= 1 \\ \\
\frac{C}{λ} &= 1 \\ \\
C &= λ 
\end{align}

b)

\begin{align}
C\int_0^{∞} e^{-tλ}dt &= 1 \\ \\
λ\int_0^{∞} e^{-700λ}dt &= 1 \\ \\
λte^{-700λ} &= 1 \\ \\
...
\end{align}

Unsure what to do, how to determine λ?
t has been re-introduced after integration

c)

Assuming λ was to be discovered in part b

\begin{align}
C\int_{2000}^{∞} e^{-tλ}dt &= P \\ \\
λ\int_{2000}^{∞} e^{-700λ}dt &= P \\ \\
\end{align}

Even if λ was known, this seems incorrect approach

t will be re-introduced again after integration?

Thank you

Comment: Concerning (b).  Exponential distributions are commonly parameterized in one of two ways: (i) with PDF $f_X(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t},$ for $t > 0,$ in which case $\lambda$ is called the _rate_ parameter and $E(X) = 1/\lambda.$. (ii) with PDF $f_X(t) = \frac{1}{\mu} e^{-t/\mu},$ for $t > 0,$.in which case $\mu$ is called the _scale_ (or mean) parameter and $E(X) = \mu.$ In your case $\lambda = 1/700.$ // I think your last displayed eqn should have $\lambda \int_{2000}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\,dt,$ with $\lambda = 1/700.$ From there, I think you can put everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part $a$ is correct. Need to fix part $b$ and $c$.

In part b, the formula for average is $$\int_0^\infty t \left[\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)\right]\,dt$$

This expression is equal to $700$.

You might want to use integration by parts or substitution to evaluate the integral and then equate to $700$ and solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: Is it always Integral( p(t) * t ) = Average? This is common formula? Thank you

Comment: That is the formula for expected value.